# Accessing User Profile on Graph Microsoft using OKHttp returns special characters

Tags: java, odata, microsoft-graph-api, okhttp

I am trying to retrieve my user profile from graph.microsoft as show [here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer#). I am using a Java library OKHttp to achieve this however the server is returning special characters in the response. I checked my headers and I did include "Accept-Encoding: gzip". However the issue is not resolved. See code under;

**Java Code**

```
Request userProfileRequest = new Request.Builder()
     .url("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me")
     .get()
     .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessTkn)
     .addHeader("Accept", "*/*")
     .addHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache")
     .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8")
     .addHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip")
     .addHeader("Connection", "keep-alive")                                 
     .addHeader("cache-control", "no-cache")
     .build();

Response userProfileResponse = client2.newCall(userProfileRequest).execute();           
System.out.println("Authorization is  " +userProfileRequest.header("Authorization"));           
System.out.println(userProfileResponse.body().string());
```

**Console output**
[image]

Answer (score 2):

OkHttp does transparent compression for you.  However by explicitly specifying `"Accept-Encoding: gzip"` you are indicating that you want gzip compression and will handle it yourself.

Removing everything except Authorization as you have done in your answer is the correct solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that worked for me was to remove all the headers except for "Authorization"

**Java Code**

```
Request userProfileRequest = new Request.Builder()
 .url("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me")
 .get()
 .addHeader("Authorization", "Bearer "+accessTkn)                                       
 .build();
```